# Permisos Android 6.0 ¿Porque cuando intento crear una carpeta en la SDcard me la crea en el almacenamiento interno del dispositivo?

Tags: android

antes que nada aclaro que soy novato en programación. Lo que estoy intentado hacer es crear una simple carpeta en la sdcard, pero me la crea en el almacenamiento interno del dipositivo. Para hacer estas pruebas estoy usando mi propio Smartphone que es un LG G4 H815 con android 6.0. La app consta de un botón, que al presionarlo crea una carpeta con el nombre "PruebaPermisosMM". Cuando inicio la app aparentemente todo funciona bien, me solicita el permiso para a acceder a fotos y archivos multimedia en el dispositivo, pero me la crea como dije anteriormente en el almacenamiento interno.

En el manifest tengo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

En build.gradle(Module:app) tengo:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "lucasandroid.pruebapermisosmm"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

El código java es:

```
package lucasandroid.pruebapermisosmm;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int CODIGO_SOLICITUD_PERMISO=123;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(checkearPermiso()){
                //Nuestra app tiene permiso
                crearCarpeta();

            }else{
                //Nuestra app no tiene permiso, entonces debo solicitar el mismo
                solicitarPermiso();
            }
        }
    });
}

private boolean checkearPermiso(){


    //Array de permisos
    String[] permisos={Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};

    for(String perms:permisos){
        int res=checkCallingOrSelfPermission(perms);
        if(!(res== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;

}

private void solicitarPermiso(){

    String[] permisos={Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){         //Verificamos si la version de android del dispositivo es mayor
       requestPermissions(permisos,CODIGO_SOLICITUD_PERMISO);  //o igual a MarshMallow
    }

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    boolean autorizado= true;   //Si el permiso fue autorizado

    switch (requestCode){
        case CODIGO_SOLICITUD_PERMISO:
            for(int res:grantResults){

                //si el usuario concedió todos los permisos
                autorizado= autorizado && (res == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            }
            break;

        default:
            //Si el usuario autorizó los permisos
            autorizado= false;
            break;
    }

    if(autorizado){
        //Si el usuario autorizó todos los permisos podemos ejecutar nuestra tarea
        crearCarpeta();
    }else {
        //Se debe alertar al usuario que los permisos no han sido concedidos
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            if(shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Los permisos de almacenamiento externo fueron denegados",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}

private void crearCarpeta(){

    File file= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(),"PruebaPermisosMM"); // Creamos un archivo llamado PruebaPermisosMM


    //Verificamos si el archivo fue creado exitosamente

    if(!file.exists()) {
        boolean ff = file.mkdir();
        if (ff){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"La carpeta fue creada exitosamente",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"La carpeta no pudo ser creada",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"La carperta ya existe",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
}
```

Aclaro tambien que cuando uso el mismo código de solicitud de permisos para el uso de la cámara o grabador de audio mediante Intent me funciona bien. No se porque tengo problemas para leer o escribir en la sd.

Comment: ¿La pregunta sería cual es la razón por la cual consideras que esta creando el directorio en el almacenamiento interno del dispositivo?
 @Lucas

Comment: @Jorgesys Gracias por tu respuesta. Tenía una confusión en lo que era el almacenamiento externo (antes de tu respuesta pensaba que almacenamiento externo solo se refería a la tarjeta sd). Ahora me surge otra duda, la memoria onBoard del Smart viene particionada en interna y externa, ahora bien ademas de la memoria externa onBoard del dispositivo tenemos tambien la tarjeta sd extraible. Mi pregunta es entonces: Es posible guardar un archivo solo en la SDcard y no en la memoria externa onBoard del dispositivo? pregunto esto porque con mi duda anterior la carpeta no aparece en la sd

Comment: @Jorgesys Es decir que aparentemente con el código que inserté arriba, crea la carpeta en la memoria externa onBoard del telefono y no en la extraible. Mi confusión venía de que cuando yo ejecutaba la app, si entraba en mi telefono en Administracion de archivos/Todos los archivos tengo dos opciones 1 Almacenamiento interno y 2 MicroSD, al   ingresar en MicroSD no aparecia la carpeta, si no que aparece en almacenamiento interno. De ahí venía mi confusión. Gracias por la aclaración!

Answer (score 1):

Comentas que la crea en el almacenamiento interno, pero estas usando:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

En esta parte de tu código, por lo tanto deberías de estar creando el archivo o directorio en el almacenamiento externo:

```
 File file= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(),"PruebaPermisosMM"); // Creamos un archivo llamado PruebaPermisosMM
```

> **[getExternalStorageDirectory()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory())** : Devuelve el directorio de
>   almacenamiento compartido / externo principal.

Si desearas obtener la ruta de almacenamiento interno en su lugar de usarías [**getFilesDir()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir())

---

¿La pregunta sería cual es la razón por la cual consideras que esta creando el directorio en el almacenamiento interno del dispositivo?

Te aconsejo leer de la documentación: **[Almacenamiento interno o externo](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html?hl=es#InternalVsExternalStorage)**